# Static circle rotates when I move kinematic rectangle in Box2d

Tags: objective-c, box2d

I am writing 2d scroller with Box2D in Xcode. Scrolling is organized by moving kinematic bodies (which all together make ground). Kinematic bodies are moved with `setlinearvelocity` function.

When dynamic body falls on this ground and stops near the wall it starts to rotate. 
Here is an image:
[image: Here is an image:]

Black circle is dynamic, blue blocks are movable kinematic bodies. When circle falls in such pit it starts to rotate. If I stop moving blue ground it does not.

How can I change this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stop moving the ground and move The ball instead. I don't see the reason why you are moving the whole terrain instead of only moving a ball. Making the terrain a static body will make the physics simulation more efficient too.

Comment: But I'm wirting a side-scroller game. How can I move camera?

Comment: Gameplay is like in "Badland" game. Ground is always moving linearly and player need to control the ball and not give it to get away from the screen

Comment: Here is a game that i made: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QvcKmHspVgg . I think it is pretty similar to what you are trying to do. In my game the ground is static and the ball is moving. You move your camera by setting its position on x axis and y axis. If you don't have no camera object that does this, then you can either make one or use some framework that has it already done for you. I would advice the later.